# ReactFX EventStreams and Replay Behavior?

Tags: java, javafx, reactive-programming, reactfx

Is there any functionality for an `EventStream` in ReactFX to cache the last value so it can be replayed to new subscribers? The RxJava `Observable` has a lot of procedures to do these kinds of tasks. I was hoping the `EventStream` might have a similiar functionality... unless I'm overlooking a reason why I would not want to do this in a GUI and I should stick to publish-only paradigms.

```
EventStream<Boolean> selectedEvt = EventStreams.changesOf(selected.selectedProperty())
.map(v -> v.getNewValue()).cache(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactFX does not have those. The idea is that if you want to remember a value, use an `ObservableValue`/[`Val`](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M4/org/reactfx/value/Val.html) instead of an `EventStream`. Turn the `ObservableValue`/`Val` into an `EventStream` when necessary. Your above example can be rewritten more simply using [`valuesOf`](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M4/org/reactfx/EventStreams.html#valuesOf-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-):

```
EventStream<Boolean> selectedEvt = EventStreams.valuesOf(selected.selectedProperty());
```

Streams created by `valuesOf` emit the current value of the underlying `ObservableValue` immediately after subscription, so they mimic the replay behavior you describe.